# How to map previous values by ID. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried asking this before and the last post was hard to understand. I have a dataset that looks at Employee IDs, their job, manager, and previous managers. What I want to do is update the previous manager column so that it displays only the most recent of the previous managers. Here is what I have:

```
 ID   Date      Job_Title      Current_Manager   Previous Manager   MGR_Change 
 1   2/2/2022     Sales            John D.           NaN               No
 1   3/2/2022     Sales            John D.          John D.            No
 1   4/2/2022     Sales            John D.          John D.            No
 2   1/14/2022    Tech             Mary S.            NaN               No 
 2   2/14/2022    Tech             Mary S.          Mary S.            No
 2   3/14/2022    Tech             Larry H.         Mary S.            Yes
 2   4/14/2022    Tech             Larry H.         Larry H.           No 
 3   7/16/2022    Advisor          Karl M.            Nan               No
 3   8/16/2022    Advisor          Sarah D.         Karl M.            Yes
 3   9/16/2022    Advisor          Michael S.       Sarah D.           Yes
```

From here I would like to only display the most recent of the previous managers in the 'Previous Manager' off of the MGR_Change column like so:

```
 ID   Date      Job_Title      Current_Manager      Previous Manager 
  1  2/2/2022     Sales           John D.           John D. 
  1  3/2/2022     Sales           John D.           John D.
  1  4/2/2022     Sales           John D.           John D. 
  2  1/14/2022    Tech            Mary S.           Mary S.
  2  2/14/2022    Tech            Mary S.           Mary S. 
  2  3/14/2022    Tech            Larry H.          Mary S.
  2  4/14/2022    Tech            Larry H.          Mary S.
  3  7/16/2022    Advisor         Karl M.           Sarah D.
  3  8/16/2022    Advisor         Sarah D.          Sarah D.
  3  9/16/2022    Advisor         Michael S.        Sarah D.
```

Comment: Is this a `pandas.Dataframe`? Are the values shown as `-` some sort of `NaN` value or are they the string `-` ?

Comment: It is in panadas they are NaN

Comment: @BorrajaXI updated the dataset on here

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
df['Previous Manager'] = df.groupby('Job_Title')['Previous Manager'].transform('last')
df = df.drop('MGR_Change', axis = 1)
```

from pandas (dataframe)

However this gives:

```
 ID       Date Job_Title Current_Manager PreviousManager
1   2/2/2022     Sales          John D.           John D.
1   3/2/2022     Sales          John D.           John D.
2   4/2/2022     Sales          John D.           John D.
2  1/14/2022      Tech          Mary S.          Larry H.
2  2/14/2022      Tech          Mary S.          Larry H.
2  3/14/2022      Tech         Larry H.          Larry H.
2  4/14/2022      Tech         Larry H.          Larry H.
3  7/16/2022   Advisor          Karl M.          Sarah D.
3  8/16/2022   Advisor         Sarah D.          Sarah D.
3  9/16/2022   Advisor       Michael S.          Sarah D.
```

Because Larry H was the last previous Tech Mgr not Mary S as in your expected output. Or have I misunderstood the requirement?